# Sitecore 10.1 install error: sql 'securityuser' already exists in the current database

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

## Error

When installing Sitecore 10.1, I'm getting the below error.

```
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "18" and "21". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:

"CREATE USER [securityuser] WITH PASSWORD = 'PvdT"
User, group, or role 'securityuser' already exists in the current database. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587 Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.

Error: User, group, or role 'securityuser' already exists in the current database.
Error count: 1.
```

[image: sc10.1 install error]

Anyone have any ideas what this could be? Scouring the web with no luck yet.

## Note

Creates the majority of the required databases and all of the databases have the `securityuser` already created inside of them.  Makes me think the SIF is creating the user, and then trying to create it again in the same db?

## Things tried

- deleting existing sql global `securityuser`
- looked for existing global sql roles named `securityuser`, didn't see any
- restarting sql server
- deleting all db's and running SIF again
- verified webdeploy is installed, have both 3.5 & 3.6
- verified SQL Server 2017 prerequisite installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your SIF tasks have been customized or modified, they are not expected to create the `securityuser` database user twice in the `Core` database. The fact that the `securityuser` exists in all your databases seems to indicate that it is a SQL Server login user and not a database user.

If you are not able to identify the reason behind the preexistence of this user, you should be able to avoid this installation error using a different name for the Security DB user name, editing the default value of the `SqlSecurityUser` parameter. This parameter is not exposed in the json configurations for the different topologies, so it might be easier to just edit its default value directly in the `XP0-sitecore.json` file, where it is defined.

This is the definition of the parameter to look for and to edit its default value (ie. `sitecoresecurityuser`):

```
"SqlSecurityUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "sitecoresecurityuser",
            "Description": "The Sql user for the Security connection string in Sitecore."
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had seen this on the web but didn't think it would help because I assumed it would have the same error but with a different user.